# Add PDF to SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, pdf

Just wondering if you can attach a PDF document to a workflow step that is assigned to a user and when the step is complete, it copies metadata from the previous steps and this attached PDF and store in a specific library?

Comment: You can modify the InfoPath form to include a link to a document. So this could be for an attachment on a list item, or a document in a library.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what SP version you use – on premise or online – you may find interesting PDF Share Forms solutions. Enterprise or OnDemand. Take a look on www.pdfshareforms.com. It goes with workflow actions to create, read and update PDF forms from workflow.